# modify a shell script to return a a name associated with the correct user id

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script that needs to be modified to return a full name with the associated user id. I really could use so help explaining in detail how to correctly modify this shell script with correct syntax. If anyone can help me understand how to do this task I would greatly appreciate any help that you can provide. I am here to learn and I am rather new to this community so if posted something incorrectly or format it wrong please let me know what i did wrong. Thanks in advance

here is the desired output:

$ ./findName.sh eiei

SETSUNA F SEIEI

$

Below is the shell script itself. The file /acct/commmon/spring-names is where all the user ids and full names are located.

```
#!/bin/sh
# findName.sh 


if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
# if there is exactly one command line arg used with the command
# do something(s).
echo "Your command line entry is: $1" > test
if [ -s ./test ]; then
cat test
else
    echo "You should not see this line as output....."
fi
else

# tell the user how to use the command and exit the script
echo "usage: `basename $0` [only_one_argument]"
exit 1
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some additional information, namely the format of the  /acct/commmon/spring-names file. In summary, you will need to replace the cat test line with an algorithm, preferably captured in a function, to parse the target file, comparing the provided user id with each line. When you find a match, grab the name and echo it out.

Comment: Sorr for the late reply. The format for spring-names is First,Middle,Last, Userid.                                                                                                                            Hunter,David,Hatch,hhatch

Comment: did you mean First,Middle,Last, Userid, Hunter,David,Hatch,hhatch  (no period at the end of UserID)?

Comment: that is correct. There is no period at the end. just commas after first, middle, last, user id

Comment: yes thats correct. no period after the user id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding exactly what you are trying to do, but I presume you would like to run a script `./findName.sh` with $1 arg. The script will then take $1 and search a file for a name? If I am wrong please correct me and I will update my answer. I made the shebang line bash since you have bash tagged.

ORIGINAL:

```
#!/bin/sh
# findName.sh 


if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
# if there is exactly one command line arg used with the command
# do something(s).
echo "Your command line entry is: $1" > test
if [ -s ./test ]; then
cat test
else
    echo "You should not see this line as output....."
fi
else

# tell the user how to use the command and exit the script
echo "usage: `basename $0` [only_one_argument]"
exit 1
```

REVISION:

```
#!/bin/bash
# findName.sh
searchFile="/acct/commmon/spring-names"

if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
  echo "You need to supply an argument to the script. Please rerun the script. syntax is below."
  echo "./`basename $0` john"
  exit 2
fi

grep -i $1 ${searchFile}
if [[ $? = "1" ]] ; then
  echo "$1 was not found in ${searchFile}"
fi
```

exit

Comment: If this appears to be what you are looking for and you have any questions, let me know and I will happily elaborate and explain anything further.

Comment: This is assuming that you have one username entry per line. If you provide further info on exactly how your spring-names file appears, then myself or the rest of the community can assist a whole lot more.

Comment: That is exactly hat i am looking for. using the script to search for the user id and return back the full name of that user. yes thanks for the reply. The spring names file is formatted like this: First,Middle,Last,Userid. All with no spaces and just a comma between each name. example: Hunter,David,Hatch,hhatch

Comment: Alright, well this will echo you out the entire line. so you if run `./findname.sh hatch`, you will see **Hunter,David,Hatch,hhatch** displayed to the screen.

Comment: You could modify what gets displayed to print out specific items etc etc, but if this works for you cool.

Comment: ya I have print out the full name like you would read on a report of something. So the output would be: Hunter David Hatch            if given user id hhatch

Answer (score 0):

Given the file format of

```
First,Middle,Last,Userid
```

the following should do what you want. Read the inline comments for more details:

```
#!/bin/bash
# findName.sh
searchFile="/acct/common/spring-names"

if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
  echo "You need to supply an argument to the script. Please rerun the script. syntax is below."
  echo "./`basename $0` john"
  exit 2
fi

# read the file line by line
while read LINE
do
    # file format: First,Middle,Last,Userid
    # set the index values based on the line format given above, change as needed.
    firstNameIndex=0
    middleNameIndex=1
    lastNameIndex=2
    userIDIndex=3

    # read the line into an array
    IFS=', ' read -r -a lineArray <<< "$LINE"

    # if the passed parameter equals the value of the line at userIDIndex 
    if [[ $1 -eq ${lineArray[$userIDIndex]} ]] ; then
        echo ${lineArray[$firstNameIndex]} ${lineArray[$middleNameIndex]} ${lineArray[$lastNameIndex]}
        exit 1 # this assumes only one instance of a user id per file, if you expect more, than delete this line.
    fi

done < "$searchFile"
```

Instead of echoing the array values like is done here, you can store them in a variable for more manipulation later, eg

```
firstName=${lineArray[$firstNameIndex]}
middleName=${lineArray[$middleNameIndex]}
lastName=${lineArray[$lastNameIndex]}
```

Given a file with the following content:

```
Hunter,David,Hatch,hhatch
```

The output would be:

```
$ ./findName.sh hhatch
Hunter David Hatch
```

Comment: I cant confirm that this works because the terminal is telling me: permission denied whenever i run the script. So until i talk with my admin about this error i am unable to test it. Thanks so much. I report back tomorrow

Comment: did you make it executable? chmod u+x findName.sh

Comment: after making it executable. i get three errors. first - line 5 searchFile: not found. Which i am guessing is because the spring-names file is located outside of my personal acct directory. second - line 7 [[: not found . third line 24 syntax error: redirection unexpected. I am sure i input the code incorrectly so i will work on it now. thanks

Comment: Check the path given to searchFile, it should match what is on your system. All's that you need is read access to it. i.e. you could  be able to do "cat /acct/common/spring-names"

Comment: Also, make sure the spacing on all of your if statments is correct. "if[[something]]" is NOT the same as "if [[ something ]]"

Comment: ya I fixed the spacing on the if statements and that helped. however i am still getting a searchfile not found error. I went into my directory and found the exact path name for the file and it still has an error. thanks for all your help but i dont think this script wants to work for me.